# angular GET request creates a cookie but "document.cookie" is an empty string

Tags: angularjs, cookies, get, csrf

What I am trying to do is to get a csrf token:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://domain.com/auth'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // ...
})
```

Then I go to Chrome's cookie manager and its there:

```
Name:   csrftoken
Content:    46DXQkAZf5LzKWwE7VPabZr4rfitVcqp
Domain: domain.com
Path:   /
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   Yes
Created:    Saturday, April 12, 2014 2:15:50 AM
Expires:    Saturday, April 11, 2015 2:15:50 AM
```

But when I console "document.cookies" it returns an empty string...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.cookie` without `s`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "unwrap" the document object

```
$document[0].cookie
```